# Line impedance in 4 layer PCB

Tags: pcb, multi-layer

i have a question..

I have a 4 layer PCB where top layer is a track layer, 1st middle layer is a GND plane, 2rd middle layer is a Vcc plane and bottom layer is a trace layer.

The layer stak table is the following (total thickness 0.81544 mm):

[image]

I use "Saturn Design PCB Toolkit", where the situation is described as follow:

[image]

for the top layer line, how thickness H must be used for the calculation of the impedance? Is correct 0.076mm? Is the correct tool for the scoope?

Thx,
Loris

Comment: There are plenty of online calculators to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `Signal Layer 1` is the ground plane, then yes, the distance H is the distance between `Signal Top` and `Signal Layer 1`.

The tool you are using is correct provided you are not using it for differential signals. If you are using differential signalling then you need the differential microstrip impedance calculator. If you want to calculate the impedance of a track on an internal layer, then you use the stripline impedance calculator.